# Как сделать приведение к типу int (*)[]

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс с матрицей который вызывает другую функцию и туда её передает

```
 class A
{
  int field[20][10];
 public:
  void method()
  {
   func((/*Здесь сделать преобразование*/)field);
  }
};
```

но функция принимает тип int (*)[]. Мне нужно в кругліх скобках сделать преобразование но не знаю как написать

Comment: func((int**)field); //нет?

Comment: @asianirish нет

Comment: Функция не должна принимать `int (*)[]`, преобразовать `int [20][10]` в этот тип нельзя, а сам `int []` является incomplete. Используйте `std::array` или какой-нибудь класс матриц.

Comment: Для двухмерных массивов по-моему всегда работало так `func(int** array){}; funct(field);`

Comment: @nick_n_a, это никогда не работало для двумерных массивов. Почитайте [здесь](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/03/30/pointers_demystified_p3.aspx), я там описал разницу.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему возник вопрос. Буквально это преобразование так и делается `(int (*)[]) field`. Т.е. так и пишите в скобках. Если вас это тем-то не устроило, значит проблема не в преобразовании.

Comment: @VTT: Почему "преобразовать нельзя"? В value context тип `int [20][10]` сам преобразуется в `int (*)[10]`, а уж это "насильно" преобразовать в `int (*)[]` труда не составит, раз уж автору так хочется. Вопрос в том, зачем это понадобилось. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Неоднозначности из-за того, что указатель и массив - это все же разные типы. Поэтому тут приведение не подойдет. Указатель на указатель и массив указателей, соответственно также разные типы. Нужно изменить функцию `func`.

В вашем случае возможны следующие решения:

**1. Функция для конкретного массива** (подойдет, если у вас функция работает только с массивами определенного и заранее известного размера)

```
void func(int matrix[][10]);
```

**2. Обобщенный шаблон**

```
template <size_t Size>
void func(int matrix[][Size]);
```

Но все же, если вы пишите на С++, лучше использовать средства из стандартной библиотеки. `std::array` практически не уступает в эффективности встроенным массивам.

Comment: Всё-таки размерность первой скобки придётся передавать в функцию, чтобы с этим можно было работать. В такой форме с `matrix` работать невозможно

Comment: @ixSci, согласен. причем передавать отдельным аргументом, т.к. `foo(int matrix[20][10])` может принять и `int a[50][10]` и, что более печально, `int a[5][10]`

Comment: Угу, старшая часть превращается в указатель. Это можно обойти вот так: `template<size_t N, size_t M>
void foo(int (&matrix)[M][N])`

Comment: Не ясно, при чем здесь "указатель и массив - это все же разные типы". Исходный массив имеет тип `int [20][10]` и запросто самостоятельно преобразуется к указателю `int (*)[10]`. Автору вопроса же нужно (зачем-то) получить `int (*)[]`. Это `reinterpret_cast` указатель -> указатель. Кроме того, что это `reinterpret_cast`, ничего страшного в нем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос выглядит так

```
class A
{
  int field[20][10];
 public:
  void method()
  {
    func((int (*)[]) field);
  }
};
```

То есть вот прямо так в скобках и пишите. (Поэтому не понятно, что у вас тут вызвало затруднения.)

А уж что функция `func` будет дальше делать с этим типом - это из вашего вопроса не ясно. Формально все, что она может сделать - это преобразовать его обратно к "правильному" типу.